# Why is my bootstrap code not responsive?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm building a custom wordpress theme and I was watching my buddy write up code for a page using bootstrap. He made it so that it is centered on his monitor. I believe he is using a 4:3 monitor. When I look at the page on my 24inch widescreen the page is not centered. What am I doing wrong that is making the page not responsive to any screen size? This is my code for the page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">

<div class="span1"></div>

<div class="span8" id="container">
<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<div class="span2">
<?php get_sidebar();?>
</div>

<div class="span1"></div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and here is the code for the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>;charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />

<center>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"></div>

<div class="span6">
<div class="logo">
<h1 id="logo-mathew">Mathew J. Mari</h1>
<h3 id="logo-attorney">Attorney At Law</h3>
</div>
</div>

<div class="span3"></div>

</div>
</center>
```

I am new to using bootstrap so maybe I'm using the wrong syntax for it to be responsive or I've left something out? I just want it to be responsive on all monitors, having it centered and utilizing a 1-8-2-1 column layout. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably best to create a fiddle for this.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem like you are using an older version of Bootstrap. The Newer version mnakes it much easier to center your elements.

Your code with the elements being used inside a container class. One of bootstrap's 3 easier method of centering a div.
And with the new bootstrap, the use of class names like col-md-1 , col-md-8 etc will be used. Make sure you read up on Bootstraps' grid system. Makes life much easier for responsive designs

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <?php get_sidebar();?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

container tag is missing must be used over the row and all other tags

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

...

Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using the old version of `Bootstrap i.e 2.3` and bootstrap has already released the new `version 3.0` so please upgrade it.

Now in the version you are using, there is another css that you need to give reference and that is for the responsive. and also add the `.container-fluid` for your main container.

Answer (score 0):

Add Class .col-centered to your page wrapper div

```
.col-centered{
       margin:0 auto;
       float : none;
       display:block;
}
```

it centered your page in any size monitor